# Does Tailscale log the IPs of devices which are connected on your account?

Tags: vpn, ip, logging, privacy, tailscale

I know a lot of VPNs say they don’t log IPs, but then have other situations internally. I’m not even sure entirely how Tailscale works on the server-side, does one device connect to Tailscale servers connecting to another device, or do the devices somehow connect directly using the software package and only send status updates to Tailscale? I need to know the level of security/privacy it’s offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailscale appears to be a VPN network built on wireguard.   As its a cloud based VPN server, and they run the servers the issue if logging is thee same as with any VPN provider.

Further, they actively advise they do logging (and let you see it) - "Tailscale’s central logging service has controllable retention periods and each node just logs some metadata about how your internal mesh is established, not Internet usage or personal information. (Read our privacy policy for more.)"   - as per https://tailscale.com/blog/how-tailscale-works/

If you are looking for a "no logs" VPN, this is not for you. They make that pretty clear in their Privacy Policy - https://tailscale.com/privacy-policy

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use Tailscale without the logging then look at [Headscale](https://github.com/juanfont/headscale):

> An open source, self-hosted implementation of the Tailscale control server